# 301 redirect to new url after changing the structure

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

It is a series of pages, The old URL structure was as follows:

```
http://www.domain.com/string.com?keyword
```

The new one is

```
http://www.domain.com/string.com?keyword-and-keyword
```

These are series of pages so after the first `&page=` follows the url

Comment: Your question is unclear, please state exactly what you have tried and what your expected redirect should be.

Comment: sorry actual url is
domain.com/string.html?keyword
the new is
domain.com/string.html?keyword-and-keyword2
so basically we have added -and-keyword2
this is a series of pages so the second old:
domain.com/string.html?keyword&page=2
the new is:
domain.com/string.html?keyword-and-keyword2&page=2
old url should 301 redictect to new